# Configure IIS URL rewrite to other apps (ASP.NET Core 6.0) both for http and https

Tags: redirect, iis, https, url-rewriting, rules

I have IIS with 2 websites pointing to the same directory one http and another https.
I need both of the to redirect to an ASP.NET Core 6.0 app when path starts with /passthrough 
The ASP.NET app is listening on 2 ports one for http and one for https 
So this is the rewrite that I want

```
http://localhost/passthrough  ->  http://localhost:5171
https://localhost/passthrough ->  https://localhost:7029
```

I would prefer URL **rewrite** over **redirect** because with rewrite the port numbers are not exposed to the user

I was able to get **http** going with **rewrite** and I was able to get **https** going with **redirect**:

```
       <rules>
            <rule name="PassThrough" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="PassThrough(/(.*))*" />
                <action type="Rewrite" url="http://localhost:5171{R:1}" appendQueryString="false" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{SERVER_PORT_SECURE}" pattern="0" />
                </conditions>
            </rule>
            <rule name="PassThroughSSL" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="PassThrough(/(.*))*" />
                <action type="Redirect" url="https://localhost:7029{R:1}" appendQueryString="false" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{SERVER_PORT_SECURE}" pattern="1" />
                </conditions>
            </rule>
        </rules>
```

**The above in web.config works**! 
But if I change **redirect** to **rewrite** on https rule (to hide port from user)

```
        <rules>
            <rule name="PassThrough" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="PassThrough(/(.*))*" />
                <action type="Rewrite" url="http://localhost:5171{R:1}" appendQueryString="false" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{SERVER_PORT_SECURE}" pattern="0" />
                </conditions>
            </rule>
            <rule name="PassThroughSSL" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="PassThrough(/(.*))*" />
                <action type="Rewrite" url="https://localhost:7029{R:1}" appendQueryString="false" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{SERVER_PORT_SECURE}" pattern="1" />
                </conditions>
            </rule>
        </rules>
```

I get an error when accessing https:

[image]
There are no useful errors in the IIS log so this is all a guess work:
So what's different?
I am thinking in case of redirect, the browser gets the 301 and makes a second request. For rewrite, IIS makes that "second" request. Since it is able to do that for http it must have something to do with the certificate? The ASP.NET app serves a different cert than what IIS is serving, may be IIS is not able to accept that other cert? or may be since it is holding the cert for the same localhost and it receives a different cert for localhost it thinks it must be invalid?
Here is the cert IIS is using :
[image]
[image]

For Kestrel / ASP.NET Core app I do not specify the cert explicitly in my code, but it serves something by default for https://localhost:7029

If look at it in the browser it shows this:
[image]
Do I have a cert related problem? They both look Ok to me. They have a different thumbprint value.

Comment: Please export the backend IIS Server certificate and Import it into IIS local machine under Trusted Store, If it doesn't work yet, you can try to debug the cause using IIS [Debug Diagnostics Tool](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=58210), this tool will generate detail log file, which will help you to identify the problem.